# Rounding elements of a formula up/down until the result is an integer

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I want to round up or down `a` until the result is an integer.

```
a = 1.2
b = 1.5
a*b*16 = 28.8
```

However, I have a criterion: `a` must be fixed to no more than 3 decimal places. So I need a calculation where the above example would output to this:

```
a = 1.25
b = 1.5
a*b*16 = 30
```

I'm actually coding something in Sass, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, whether it be written in JavaScript or whatever. I just need help formulating this confusing calculation!

Criteria:
**`a`** must have no more than **3 decimal places**.
**`the result`** must be an **integer**.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Define a "fixed" number?

Comment: No decimal places. An integer :)

Comment: 1.25 and 1.5 are not integers.

Comment: This is confusing. Is 16 a constant? B a variable? Is B also 3 dec. places or less?

Comment: The result must be an integer. `a` must be fixed. I have updated my post to make this more clear. Yes, 16 is a constant. `b` and `16` are arbitrary.

Comment: How to round number to desired places: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/tmUqR/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guarantee that the result will be an integer if you limit the precision of the variables, no matter what method you use.

**Examples:**

- If `b` = 3, then `a` = 30 / (16 × 3) = 30/48 = 5/8 = 0.625
  In this case, 0.625 × 3 × 16 = 30 exactly.
- If `b` = 7, then `a` = 30 / (16 × 7) = 30/112 = 15/56 = 0.267857...
  Rounding `a` results in 0.268, and 0.268 × 7 × 16 = 30.016, which is the closest you can come to 30.  In other words, *there is no value of `a` that will satisfy onthe criteria*, and 0.268 is the best you can do.

But you *can* solve for the *best* value to make the result as close as possible to an integer.

Solve the equation for the desired variable, then round to the appropriate number of decimals.

```
a = 30. / (16. * b); // true value
a = ((int) (1000 * a + 0.5)) / 1000; // round to 3 decimals
```

Most modern languages provide library functions to do the rounding for you; I wrote it "long-hand" so you can understand how it works.

Comment: Hmm… but if I round `a` then the calculation will no longer result in the integer that is needed.

Comment: What if… I did a loop to find all of the possible variables that did not have any more than 3 decimal places, and then used the closest result? That works in my head… no idea how I'd code it.

Comment: See my comment to one of the other answers: a loop simply uses trial and error to find the result given by this formula.  It's like saying, "I don't know enough math (or am too lazy) to figure out the answer, so I'll try **every possible combination** until I find one I like."  Some problems _must_ be solved through trial and error because there is no closed-form solution.  This is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. However, given the criteria for this formula, surely trial and error is the only solution? Unless there's a formula that can do it. I understand that the method you provide will give the closest possibly to an integer, but it's a criteria. It has to be an integer (don't ask what I'm doing, it's to do with pixels and stuff!)

Comment: Try it both ways.  You'll find that you arrive at the same answer.  My first example shows what happens if an exact solution exists: the formula calculates it (and trial-and-error will find it).  The second shows what happens if there isn't: the formula finds the value of `a` that comes closest to producing an integer (and trial-and-error will simply fail).  You can't break the laws of math simply by asking the question again and again and hoping for a different answer.  :-(

Comment: I guess the ultimate solution here, then, is to use trial and error, but with a limit. If an answer can't be found realistically, then that's for me to provide a fallback in my code. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: You still seem to be missing the point.  If a solution exists, then **trial and error will give you the same result as a formula,** but it will **take longer**.  If no solution exists, **the formula will provide the "best" solution** and **the trial-and-error loop will never terminate.**  Again, I _strongly_ suggest you try solving both ways until you understand this.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around your explanation. It's not you, it's me! My maths isn't great. I *think* I understand what you're saying, but in your calculation, the result (30) appears to be a constant. Effectively, I need a way of saying this: "hey, I have one variable (`1.2`) and two constants (`1.5` and `16`). Multiply these numbers and give me an integer, but if you need to change the variable, you can… just to no more than 3 decimal places".

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: So `b` is now a constant?! In that case you have a result, two constants and a variable. The result depends only on the variable. So you can go backwards and calculate the variable from the result (as Adam has said).

Comment: Remember, the result is also sort-of a variable. The aim is to find the best match where the result is an integer and the variable has no more than 3 decimal places. I swear trial and error is the only way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = Math.round(a*b*16);
a = i/b/16;
a = a.toFixed(2);
b = i/16/a;
```

test om i==a*b*16